# Search query failed

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am currently working on ms access 2010 and coding in vba. I would like to search between a given start and end date but it just doesnt query at all.

my sql query will be as such, and I have taken the start and end value from  calender.

```
"SELECT [fields] WHERE (DateofIssue BETWEEN" & TextBoxStartDate.value & " AND " & TextBoxEndDate.value)
```

I have included the () because I do have other conditions to check for too, is the () ok to be used this way?

I have seen people adding in # and have tried and failed, example:

```
"SELECT [fields] WHERE (DateofIssue BETWEEN #" & TextBoxStartDate.value & "# AND #" & TextBoxEndDate.value & "#")
```

I have already changed the date format in the datasheet and forms to `dd/mm/yyyy`. I check in the datasheet view, the dates are displayed in the form of example `28/05/2013`. and I tried to do a bit of debugging by adding in msgbox for the respective textboxes mentioned above. they showed 2`8/5/201`3 instead of `28/05/201`3. there is a missing 0 in the month, is this the reason why?

any suggestions what could be the issue and how can I remedy? any help will be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need # symbol .. So try this

```
"SELECT [fields] WHERE (DateofIssue >= #" & format(TextBoxStartDate.value,"MM/dd/yyyy") & "# AND DateofIssue <= #" & format(TextBoxEndDate.value, "MM/dd/yyyy") & "#")
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the help, appreciate it!

Comment: @user2423986 : Is this figured out your problem ? .. If it is, better you vote this as the answer ..

Answer (score 0):

You do need the # symbol surrounding the dates.

It does not matter how your table is displaying the dates. It's all stored the same.

The leading zero does not matter.

My understanding in Access, queries expect U.S. formats of dates. Try using either **mm/dd/yyyy** or the ISO standard of **yyyy-mm-dd**